# What does a[i] + 1 denote for a[N][N]

Tags: c++

I'm having difficulty in understanding this piece of code.

What does `a[i] + 1` mean? And what is `cin >> (a[i] + 1)` doing?

```
char a[N][N];
for(int i = 1;i <= n;i++) {
        cin >> (a[i] + 1);
        for(int j = 1;j <= m;j++) 
            if(a[i][j] == '=') 
                merge(i,j + 1000);
    }
```

The entire code is here: https://codeforces.com/contest/1131/submission/50515808

Comment: Did you try to compile that?

Comment: Yeah, as the other guy implies, this shouldn't even work.

Comment: yes i tried it but im getting an error...But ive seen it written in code multiple times but havent understood what it does

Comment: Could you give us an example with a working code that uses this syntax? You might have misread the code or something. We'd also like some context.

Comment: ive edited my question now

Comment: And now we can see that `a` is NOT declared as a character.

Comment: @physics123 show how a[] is declared as well

Comment: Posting a proper [mcve] should be your priority from the start.

Comment: @Blaze yes sorry i read the declaration wrong .. 'a' has been declared as a 2 dimensional array a[N][N]...So a[i] would be a pointer to the (i+1)th row right?

Comment: Edit your question to make it minimal and complete as @StoryTeller suggested.

Comment: In this case `a[i] + 1` denotes the memory location of `a` increased by  `N*i + 1`. And with `cin >> (a[i] + 1);` it's writing characters to that and the following memory (depending on how much it's writing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`a` is an array of arrays. That's what multi-dimensional arrays *are* in C++. It has `N` elements, each of which has the type `char[N]` (an array type).

`a[i]` is an lvalue expression of an array type, so one can think of it as `char (&)[N]`, a reference to an array of N characters. The `i`-th one.

Since arrays have the property of decaying to a pointer that points at their first elements when appearing in most expressions, `a[i] + 1` is that pointer being used in pointer arithmetic. It's equal to `&a[i][1]`. The whole thing is a `char*` that points to the start of a buffer with size `N-1`.

So on the whole, `cin >> (a[i] + 1)` uses the `char*` overload of `operator>>` for istream. To store characters in the buffer `a[i]`, but skipping the first one. And it's only going to work upto [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20). When the `char*` overloads are finally [replaced with overloads that take a reference to an array of a known bound](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/operator_gtgt2). Because the `char*` overload is susceptible to buffer overruns.